# ReactJS remove child element created through count

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I have two components, a TrackSection(the Parent element) which has a button that creates a TrackItem(child) every time it is clicked. The child elements are built through a variable numTracks which increments every time the button is clicked. The add button works fine but i'm having issues deleting a TrackItem from the array. I tried referencing the track_items directly but it won't let me.

I'm very new to React and Frontend development. Any other tips would be appreciated!

TrackSection.js

```
class TrackSection extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      numTracks: 0,
    };
  }

  onAddTrack = () => {
    this.setState({
      numTracks: this.state.numTracks + 1,
    });
  };

  onDeleteTrack = () =>{
   //????
  };


  render() {
    const track_items = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.state.numTracks; i += 1) {
      track_items.push(<TrackItem key={i} id={i} onDeleteTrack = {this.onDeleteTrack(i)}/>);
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <Button onClick={this.onAddTrack}>
            +new track
        </Button>
        {track_items}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

TrackItem.js

```
class TrackItem extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            id: this.props.id,
            name: '',
        }
    }

    render(){
    var onDeleteTrack = this.props.onDeleteTrack
    return(
        <Grid container direction="row">
            <Grid item direction="column">
            //Dummy 
            </Grid>
            <button onClick={() => onDeleteTrack(this.props.id)}>Delete</button>
        </Grid>
        );
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

You are using an array index as the React key, and the `id`. When you remove an element from the array you may remove it from the array, but since the items shift up to fill the "hole" now all the elements in the array have incorrect "id"/index values.

## Solution

Don't use a mapped array index as a React key.

Example solution uses an incrementing id, as before, but also stores the array in state. This allows you to consistently increment the id key ***and*** retain a static id with each element.

```
class TrackItem extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      id: this.props.id,
      name: ""
    };
  }

  render() {
    var onDeleteTrack = this.props.onDeleteTrack;
    return (
      <Grid container direction="row">
          <Grid item direction="column">
          //Dummy
          </Grid>
      <button onClick={() => onDeleteTrack(this.props.id)}>Delete {this.props.id}</button>
      </Grid>
    );
  }
}

class TrackSection extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      tracks: [],
      id: 0,
    };
  }

  onAddTrack = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      tracks: [...prevState.tracks, prevState.id],
      id: prevState.id + 1,
    }));
  };

  onDeleteTrack = (id) =>{
   this.setState(prevState => ({
     tracks: prevState.tracks.filter(el => el !== id)
   }))
  };


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.onAddTrack}>
            +new track
        </button>
        {this.state.tracks.map(track => (
          <TrackItem key={track} id={track} onDeleteTrack = {this.onDeleteTrack}/>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Edit affectionate-field-2l16kreactjs-remove-child-element-created-through-count]

Answer (score 0):

Be careful about doing too much logic in your render function, as your current solution would recreate all the TrackItem's every time you add a new item. So React can't do optimization magic.

Second remark, now you are just having a counter, so removing a element in the middle would probably not have the effect you are looking for. I assume the track items will be having some data to them. Like name, etc. So just store those values in the state and render each item.

Here is a sample solution, modify for your needs:

```
class TrackSection extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      tracks: []
    };
  }

  onAddTrack = () => {
    // Probably not the best way to create a id
    const randomId = Math.random().toString();

    const newTrack = {
      id: randomId,
      name: "Some name" + randomId
    };

    const newTracks = [
      // the tracks we allready have added
      ...this.state.tracks,
      // add a new track to the end
      newTrack
    ];

    // Replace state
    this.setState({
      tracks: newTracks
    });
  };

  onDeleteTrack = (id) => {
    // Keeps all tracks that don't match 'id'
    const tracksWithOutDeleted = this.state.tracks.filter(
      (track) => track.id !== id
    );

    // Replace the tracks, so now its gone!
    this.setState({
      tracks: tracksWithOutDeleted
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.onAddTrack}>+new track</button>
        {
          // Loop over tracks we have in state and render them
          this.state.tracks.map((track) => {
            return (
              <TrackItem
                id={track.id}
                name={track.name}
                onDeleteTrack={this.onDeleteTrack}
              />
            );
          })
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And the TrackItem.js:

```
class TrackItem extends Component {
  render() {
    const { onDeleteTrack, id, name } = this.props;
    return (
      <>
        <button onClick={() => onDeleteTrack(id)}>Delete {name}</button>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```